# DOM Modul is only loading in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, polymer

I am using Polymer for my Login Form. For this I am using this:

```
    <dom-module id="my-form">
                        <template> 
                            <paper-card heading="Login">
                                <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="includes/process_login.php">
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <div class="loginerror" id="loginerror">
                                            <p><font color="red">Diese Benutzer/Passwort kombination <br> ist uns unbekannt.</font></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <paper-input label="Login" id="email" name="email" size="25" value=""></paper-input>
                                        <paper-input label="Password" type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" value=""></paper-input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-actions">
                                        <paper-button raised value="Login" type="submit" on-click="submitForm">Login</paper-button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </paper-card>

                        </template>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            Polymer({
                                is: "my-form",
                                submitForm: function () {
                                    formhash(this.$.form, this.$.password);
                                    this.$.form.submit();
                                },
                                ready: function () {
                                    this.$.form.addEventListener('iron-form-response', this.formResponse);
                                    this.$.form.addEventListener('iron-form-error', this.formError);
                                },
                                formResponse: function (e) {
                                    console.log("Server Response: ", e.detail);
                                },
                                formError: function (e) {
                                    console.log("Form Error: ", e.detail);
                                },
                                listeners: {
                                    'iron-form-response': 'formResponse'
                                }
                            });
                        </script>
                    </dom-module>
<my-form></my-form>
```

But now I have the problem that the Login Form is only working in Google Chrome on the Desktop. Not in the Google Chrome App or any other browser. And I don't know why.
In Google Chrome it looks like this:

[image: GoogleChrome]

And in any other browser like this:

[image: AnyOtherBrowser]

But how can I change this. Is this a Bug ?

Nils

Comment: Do you load the polyfills? See for example https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html (web-components)

Comment: Yes. And I really don't know why it dosen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
You need to add this to your code:

```
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
                Polymer({
                    is: 'my-form'
                });
    });
```

Comment: I'm working cross browser without doing anything like the above.  I have found though that other browsers aren't so forgiving of little errors.  I think in one place I specified a date attribute as '2016-1-1' and chrome took that without any issues where as firefox and safari both saw that as invalid date.

Comment: That is not necessary in general, only if you declare elements in your main document. Here's a [link to the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#main-document-definitions).